# How to unzip or read password protected (XML data) Zip file in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, zip, unzip

I am new on working with extracting zip file
which is password protected

I have a xml zipfile which is password protected
on uploading the password protected zip file from the frontend
Need to open it from password and read that xml file

Is their any way to handle it in javascript or in angularjs

Or

If you have the soution please share it here

Thanks in advance.